# Unable to load a form in codeigniter from a controller

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a simple sign up/Login registration project in php/codeigniter

and I always get this particular error while clicking on the Sign in or the Register button

**Error: "The requested URL /CI/user/login was not found on this server."**

Here is the Controller file user.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class User extends CI_Controller{   
     public function __construct()
     {

      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('user_model');

     }

     public function index()

     {
      if(($this->session->userdata('user_name')!=""))
      {
       $this->welcome();
      }

      else{
       $data['title']= 'Home';
       $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
       $this->load->view("registration_view.php", $data);
       $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
      }}

     public function welcome()
     {
      $data['title']= 'Welcome';
      $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
      $this->load->view('welcome_view.php', $data);
      $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
     }

     public function login()
     {
      $email=$this->input->post('email');
      $password=md5($this->input->post('pass'));

      $result=$this->user_model->login($email,$password);
      if($result) $this->welcome();
      else        $this->index();
     }

     public function thank()
     {
      $data['title']= 'Thank';
      $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
      $this->load->view('thank_view.php', $data);
      $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
     }

     public function registration()
     {
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      // field name, error message, validation rules
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('con_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

      if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {
       $this->index();
      }
      else
      {
       $this->user_model->add_user();
       $this->thank();
      }
     }

     public function logout()
     {
      $newdata = array(
      'user_id'   =>'',
      'user_name'  =>'',
      'user_email'     => '',
      'logged_in' => FALSE,
      );

      $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata );
      $this->session->sess_destroy();
      $this->index();
     }
    }
    ?>
```

Here is the view file registration_view.php

```
    <html>
<div id="content">
<div class="signup_wrap">
<div class="signin_form">


 <?php echo form_open("user/login"); ?>

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value=""/>

  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value=""/>

  <input type="submit" class="" value="Sign in"/>

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>




</div><!--<div class="signin_form">-->
</div><!--<div class="signup_wrap">-->





<div class="reg_form">
<div class="form_title">Sign Up</div>
<div class="form_sub_title">It's free and anyone can join</div>



<?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); ?>
<?php echo form_open("user/registration");?>

  <p>
  <label for="user_name">User Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="<?php echo set_value('user_name'); ?>" />
  </p>

  <p>
  <label for="email_address">Your Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" value="<?php echo set_value('email_address'); ?>" />
  </p>

  <p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" />
  </p>

  <p>
  <label for="con_password">Confirm Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="con_password" name="con_password" value="<?php echo set_value('con_password'); ?>" />
  </p>

  <p>
  <input type="submit" class="greenButton" value="Submit" />
  </p>

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div><!--<div class="reg_form">-->
</div><!--<div id="content">-->

</html>
```

**I think the main problem is with form_open ('form');**

Here is the htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: did you place `.htaccess` file?? or try `<?php echo form_open("User/login"); ?>`

Comment: @Abdulla just added it

Comment: capitalize your controller `form_open("User/login")`

Comment: @Abdulla So should I name my user.php controller to User.php?

Comment: no no. just use in view and c

Comment: @Abdulla I used what you told me but still no use. Same error. Do you think its the configuration problem? Because the config settings have been a real pain in the back side tbh

Comment: @Abdulla this is my base url setting 

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CI';

Comment: keep empty. Don't give any vales for it

Comment: @Abdulla not working :(

Comment: what is the actual url it takes you to?

Comment: @webcrazymaniac when i click on the sign in button it takes me to http://localhost/CI/User/login

Comment: try changing CI dir name to something else, and try the modified url

Comment: @webcrazymaniac should i change it to ci?

Comment: no, something other then ci, or CI

Comment: @webcrazymaniac i just changed the name of the dir only and nothing else, should i make some other changes?

Comment: no, try the url, localhost/[new_name]/user/login

Comment: @webcrazymaniac i did what you told me to but still the same error, i think the issue is something else, not the name of the dir name

Comment: same error like 'Error: "The requested URL /**CI**/user/login was not found on this server."'?

Comment: @webcrazymaniac yes but  i changed the name to project 
The requested URL /project/user/login was not found on this server

Comment: is 'project' a subfolder of Controllers dir?

Comment: @webcrazymaniac First its project which contains the subfolders application, system etc and the application folder contains the views,models and controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass complete url to the form_open function like this

```
   echo form_open(base_url()."/user/login");
```

Comment: Tried it, still no use :(

Answer (score 0):

change this: 
`<?php echo form_open("user/login"); ?>`
to this:
`<?php echo form_open(base_url()."User/login"); ?>`

 in config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

after that if doesn't work call your method from url if work correct post data to your method!!!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** in your htaccess file, change to. (Another suggestion, no guarantee)

```
RewriteBase /project
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: well, I can say for sure that your problem lies in the fact you try to run codeigniter in a subfolder of your domain. It can be done, but there are a few server setting to be changed (I don't know how to make those). It would be more simple to change your httpd.conf in apache, and make your CI dir (or project), your root dir for the server. But that would make it impossible to access other projects you may have on the same dir level. What you are looking for is 'installing CodeIgniter in subfolder'. If you google that you may find some solutions.

Comment: So what do you think I should do? I mean, should I just take the codeigniter folder out of the folder and make it the main folder?

Comment: that's what I did on my developing enviroment, and my life is much more simple. I also run CodeIgniter in a sub folder on a live server(that's why I say it can be done), but the settings were made by a server administrator, one of my colleagues, something I may never understand :)

Comment: ok i will try making a main folder out of the codeigniter sub folder

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` whichever exists. Basically, apache does not acknowledge the `.htaccess` file unless you declare the `AllowOverride` directive.

So, you have to open up the said config file, and add this to the bottom, if your full path to the sub-directory is `/var/www/html/subdirectory/`

```
<Directory /var/www/html/subdirectory/>
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

And don't forget to restart apache!